# How can I display the users profile pic using the facebook graph api?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to display the users profile picture inside of my applications canvas page, is there a way to do that using the graph api?

I know I can do it using FBML but I would also like to pass the profile pic to a flash game I am making, so I would have to get the profile pic from the api and send it as a variable, here is the code I have thus far,

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY,
    'cookie' => true,
    'domain' => 'myurl/facebook-test'
));

$session = $facebook->getSession();

        $uid = $facebook->getUser();
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');

        $updated = date("l, F j, Y", strtotime($me['updated_time']));

        echo "Hello " . $me['name'] . $me['picture'] . "<br />";
  echo "<div style=\"background:url(images/bg.jpg); width:760px; height:630px;\">" . "You last updated your profile on " . $updated . "</div>" . "<br /> your uid is" . $uid;
```

`$me['picture']` does not seem to be working, but I am still very new to the graph api, and I am probably making a few very amateur mistakes!

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Knowing the user id the URL for their profile picture is:-

```
http://graph.facebook.com/[UID]/picture
```

where in place of [UID] you place your $uid variable, and that URL can be passed to flash

Comment: Now it seems to return a redirect (302) response, but if you follow that you will get the right image. 
Also you can ?redirect=false to the url to get a JSON response which contains the final URL to the picture.

Comment: hello any one is having idea? why the response is coming null while it is called from android device? I was using this only in my application but now image is not coming using this method.

Comment: Still works! Make sure you use `https` instead of `http`, if you're using `Picasso`.

Comment: Obsoleted. OAuth is required for now.

Comment: Is there any way to find large size profile pictures?

Answer (score 81):

to get different sizes, you can use the type parameter:

You can specify the picture size you want with the type argument, which should be one of square (50x50), small (50 pixels wide, variable height), and large (about 200 pixels wide, variable height): http://graph.facebook.com/squall3d/picture?type=large.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't seem to find this anywhere, but i knew it was possible!

Comment: What's even better is that width/height params works too eg: width=140&height=140

Answer (score 22):

You can also resize the profile picture by providing parameters as shown below.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[UID]/picture?width=140&height=140
```

would work too.

Comment: The FB documentation  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/picture  says `When height and width are both used, the image will be scaled as close to the dimensions as possible and then cropped down.`, does it mean they will return some predefined size 123x123 when I am asking for 150x150?

Comment: Actually found answer myself: when asking for `/picture?width=450x450` I am  redirected to image: `https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-1/c120.0.480.480/p480x480/10525666_10154418313275648_598202092662269872_n.jpg?somequerystring` which is a `480x480` image. And when I am  asking for `/picture?width=300&height=300` I get redirected to `https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-1/c80.0.320.320/p320x320/10525666_10154418313275648_598202092662269872_n.jpg` which is `320x320` image. So you're right about predefined sizes.

Answer (score 7):

```
  //create the url
  $profile_pic =  "http://graph.facebook.com/".$uid."/picture";

 //echo the image out
 echo "<img src=\"" . $profile_pic . "\" />";
```

**Works fine for me**

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**: So facebook has changed it again! No more searching by username - have amended the answer below...

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{{UID}}/picture?redirect=false&height=200&width=200
```

- UID = the profile or page id
- redirect either returns json (false) or
  redirects to the image (true)
- height and width is the crop
- does not require authentication

e.g. https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?redirect=false&height=200&width=200

[Facebook Graph picture doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/picture)

Comment: This is no longer valid (#803) Cannot query users by their username (zuck)

Comment: @Roni But you still can query by UID. It works for me with UID.

Comment: @RredCat I didn't say anything about UID, just the username - the UID query will probably work for a very long time

Comment: `http://graph.facebook.com/[UID]/picture` works! 
Is there an upper limit to the number of times I can issue this API call?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code that worked for me!

Assuming that you have a valid session going,

```
//Get the current users id
$uid = $facebook->getUser();

//create the url
$profile_pic =  "http://graph.facebook.com/".$uid."/picture";

//echo the image out
echo "<img src=\"" . $profile_pic . "\" />";
```

Thanx goes to Raine, you da man!

Answer (score 1):

I was having a problem fetching profile photos while using CURL. I thought for a while there was something wrong my implementation of the Facebook API, but I need to add a bit to my CURL called:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

One very important thing is that like other Graph API request, you won't get the JSON data in response, rather the call returns a HTTP REDIRECT to the URL of the profile pic. So, if you want to fetch the URL, you either need to read the response HTTP header or you can use FQLs.

Answer (score -1):

The returned data is the binary data of the image type. If you use JavaScript to retrieve the user photo, please get the photo data as blob type in a XMLHttpRequest, and then retrieve the blob URL from the response. For your reference:

```
 var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
 var photoUri=config.endpoints.graphApiUri + "/v1.0/me/photo/$value";
 request.open("GET",photoUri);
 request.setRequestHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+token);
 request.responseType = "blob";
 request.onload = function (){
        if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
               var image = document.createElement("img");
               var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
               var blobUrl = url.createObjectURL(request.response);
               image.src = blobUrl;
               document.getElementById("UserShow").appendChild(image);
        }
 };
 request.send(null);
```