# cache http://graph.facebook.com/[UID]/picture call?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Thanks to [How can I display the users profile pic using the facebook graph api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012905/how-can-i-display-the-users-profile-pic-using-the-facebook-graph-api/3012980#3012980) I found out I can retrieve profile picture via

```
http://graph.facebook.com/[UID]/picture
```

but this redirects to an image like for example:

http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/hs1346.snc4/161671_1096373372_1486835_q.jpg

My first question is when I want to display this image should I do(returned from API)

```
<img src="http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/hs1346.snc4/161671_1096373372_1486835_q.jpg" />
```

or should I call the api:

```
<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/alfredwesterveld/picture" />
```

Does http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/hs1346.snc4/161671_1096373372_1486835_q.jpg show my updated profile picture, if update my profile picture on Facebook or does show my old profile picture. I ask these question because when I could call an absolute URL(which resolves to an image immediately) I could safe myself a redirect(round-trip). I believe this could add up especially when I want to get all profile pictures from the visitors of my website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to display the picture of a user use the second method, that's the good one:

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/[UID]/picture" alt="" />
```

Doing like this you'll be sure that each time you'll receive the updated picture of the user, if it was changed recently.

**later edit**

Related to the cache issue, if you want to save the direct urls in order to improve caching of the pictures I don't suggest doing so because those urls are changing each time a user changes the profile picture, so you might end up displaying an older picture even though the user actually changed it recently.

Comment: You asked which of the two methods is better to use. And I told you which one and gave an example + some comments about why you should use this. If this is not want you want from your question then what is ?

Comment: Check out what I edited. I think that's what you wanted from the start :)

Answer (score 1):

hi why you not use fbml tag for this?

```
<fb:profile-pic uid='UID' width='50' height='50'></fb:profile-pic>
```

EDIT
hello if you want to get photo uploaded by the user then you can get by this

```
$photos=json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token='.$cookie['access_token']));
foreach ($photos->data as $friend)
{
?>
<img src="<?=$friend->source?>" width="50" height="50">
<?php    
}
```

All images uploaded by the user can be easily captured

Comment: thanks, I guess I could also use this fmbl tag. But I am wondering if you have more information about the other image?

Comment: about images mean? Images uploaded by users?