# How should i get Facebook user friend list and their profile picture's using Graph API in PHP?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

> I am using this code to get the user friend's list. For profile picture i am unable to find any reference please guide if you know the process

```
$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
$iLimit=99;
if($user_id) {

     // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
     // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.

     try {

       $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
      echo"<h3>";

echo 'Name: ' . $user_profile['name'];
echo"</h3>";
$profile_pic =  "http://graph.facebook.com/".$user_id."/picture";

echo "<img src=\"" . $profile_pic . "\" />"; 
$user_friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends', 'GET' );
print_r($user_friends);            //Given NULL Value 
echo "</pre>";\
```

> Returning null value

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the facebook graph api docs
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/friend-list/
and here is the code with tutorial 
http://www.sanwebe.com/2011/10/facebook-friends-list-pagewise-with-php
Hope it helps !

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/profile-picture-source/ and here are docs for profile picture.

Comment: I already checked it and still unable to get the list if you know the process please help @Poria

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012905/how-can-i-display-the-users-profile-pic-using-the-facebook-graph-api try this

Comment: this is for user profile picture and i want user friend's proflie picture's @Poria

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835028/getting-list-of-facebook-friends-with-latest-api

Comment: still the same @Poria

Comment: can you create some working fiddle ? so that i can help out there